# React, ReactCSSTransitionGroup appear works but not leave

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have a little global "toast" react component I am building. It feeds off a list of toasts I provide to it from the redux state. I am trying to get them to animate in and out with react's `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` , I seem to be able to get the enter/active animation, but not the leave.

Here is my component:

```
   export default class FollainToast extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.mapToasts = this.mapToasts.bind(this);
  }

  mapToasts() {
    return this.props.display.toasts.map((toast) => {
      return (
        <div className="my-toast" key={toast.id}>
          <p className="toast-msg">{toast.msg}</p>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.display && this.props.display.toasts && this.props.display.toasts.length > 0) {
      return (
        <div className="row">
          <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
            transitionName="toasty"
            transitionAppear
            transitionAppearTimeout={400}
            transitionEnter
            transitionEnterTimeout={400}
            transitionLeave
            transitionLeaveTimeout={400}
            >
          {this.mapToasts()}
          </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

So, it takes a prop called display which has a list of `toasts` inside of it and renders them. I am thinking it might have to do with the fact that I have the `render()` function wrapped in some logic to make sure the toasts but of the objet is there ( or dont' render) but i'm not honestly sure.

Here is the css I am using for the animations

```
.toasty-appear, .toasty-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transform:   translate(-250px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

.toasty-appear.toasty-appear-active, .toasty-enter..toasty-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  transform:   translate(0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.665, 0.320, 1), linear;
}

.toasty-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transform:   translate(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.665, 0.320, 1), linear;
}
.toasty-leave.toasty-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transform:   translate(-250px,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}
```

The enter animation is working great, however the when the toast is removed from the toasts list, it immediately disappears off the dom. Thanks for reading!

Comment: what if instead of returning null, you change it to not visible, something that re-renders it?

Comment: According to [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html), the transition for leave needs to be in `toasty-leave-active` (your's is in `toasty-leave`). For debugging purposes, I would increase the transition time for `toasty-leave` to 10 seconds in `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` and leave. Then, test your CSS.